# How to export a container in Singularity

Tags: singularity-container

I would like to move an already built container from one machine to another. What is the proper way to migrate the container from one environment to another?

I can find [here](https://singularity.lbl.gov/docs-export) the image.export command, but this is for an older version of the software. I am using version 3.5.2.

The container I wish to export is a `--sandbox` container. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Singularity allows you to easily convert between a sandbox and a production build.

For example:

```
singularity build lolcow.sif docker://godlovedc/lolcow  # pulls and builds a container

singularity build --sandbox lolcow_sandbox/ lolcow.sif # converts from container to a writable sandbox

singularity build lolcow2 lolcow_sandbox/ # converts from sandbox to container
```

Once you have a production SIF or SIMG, you can easily transfer the file and convert as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`singularity build` generates a file that you can copy between computers just like any other file. The only things it needs is the singularity binary installed on the new host server.

The difference when using `--sandbox` is that you get a modifiable directory instead of single file. It can still be run elsewhere, but you may want to tar it up first so you're only moving a single file. Then you can untar it and run as normal on the new host.

Comment: Yes this is what I also believed. But I have been trying to **tar** the container which is built with sandbox but I get compression errors. Should I just ignore them ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the errors. If they're permission based, you'll need to tar with sudo. If that's still failing, you could create a read only image from the sandbox (`sudo singularity build my_image.sif my_sandbox/`, transfer that, then make a new sandbox on the new host (`sudo singularity build --sandbox my_sandbox my_image.sif`).